# GeoServer not wrapping mutliline text on \n

Tags: geoserver, labeling

I am trying to display labels from attribute which contents multiline texts. The lines in texts are divided with \n. Can GeoServer wrap these texts on \n?

Answer (score 1):

SLD is an XML based language so newlines are just another type of whitespace. If you need a new line you need to wrap in a cdata block.

Comment: but my labels are coming from attribute and the new line deliminator \n is already included in attribute content.

Comment: I found here a mention of processing strings with \n - http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Automatic-Label-Wrapping-Throw-GeoServer-a-curve-td3806617.html. According to what aaime writes, \n should be treated as line break. But in my style this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have auto wrap turned on

Comment: yes. here is the  CSS:
'* {
    label: [WS];
   label-auto-wrap: 150;
}'

Comment: Is there anything that I can try to figure this out?